# RequireJS: can you get the filename of the parent JS file which "define"d the current file?

Tags: javascript, magento, requirejs, magento2

I have a Magento 2 website which uses RequireJS extensively. Lots of JavaScript files are loaded via RequireJS and those files can themselves load several more files via `define`.

Is it possible to print the name of the parent file (or line, or function) which requested the current file be loaded? This would help generate some kind of hierarchical tree view of all JS files being loaded.